# How can I pass a function to run to a function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to check weather a certain property exists before I can run the function listed in the add-on menu for a google spreadsheet.  Rather than creating a copy of the same check for each function I would like to create a single function that I can pass the function to run as a parameter.   How can I do this?

Below is my non functioning test code, but you may get the idea.

```
function testRun(){
  //in practicality this would be an add-on menu
  test1Check('test1()');
}


function test1(){
  Logger.log("Function Ran");
}


function test1Check(functionToRun){
      var labels = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('labels');
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  if (!labels) {
    var result = ui.alert(
      'You have not yet set up the page for gClassFolders',
      'Would you like to do this now?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    setupGCF();
  } 

  } 
  else { 
    functionToRun;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the () from the parameter sent, and add () to the variable in the function.

```
function testRun(){

  test1Check(test1);
}


function test1(){
  Logger.log("Function Ran");
}


function test1Check(functionToRun){
      var labels = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('labels');
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  if (!labels) {
    var result = ui.alert(
      'You have not yet set up the page for gClassFolders',
      'Would you like to do this now?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    setupGCF();
  } 

  } 
  else { 
    functionToRun();
  }
}
```